# Two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of permutation group($G$).such that $H$ is normal in $K$ and $K$ is normal in $G$ but $H$ is not normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there exist any subgroups $H$ and $K$ of permutation group($G$).such that $H$ is normal in $K$ and $K$ is normal in $G$ but $H$ is not normal in $G$?

Comment: **Any** group can be seen as a permutation group by Cayley's Theorem. Do you mean *the* permutation group $\;S_n\;$ , for some $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ , or even perhaps $\;S_X\;$ , for some set $\;X\;$ ?

Comment: Yes, such examples are not too hard to find (though interestingly, if the subgroup $K$ is a symmetric group of degree $\neq 6$ then this cannot happen).

Comment: Hint: try $S_4$. What @Tobias says is true because if $\mathrm{out}(K)=1$ then every normal subgroup $H\unlhd K$ is also characteristic in $K$ and therefore normal in $G$. However $S_6$ actually has the same property: every normal subgroup is characteristic, even though there are outer automorphisms. (It just so happens that they must all fix $A_6$, because $A_6\cap \theta(A_6)$ would be of index $2$ in $A_6$ but $A_6$ is simple.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full example:

Let $G = S_4$.
Let $K$ be the subgroup consisting of double transpositions (and the identity). Thus, $K$ is normal in $G$ of order $4$ (since there are precisely $3$ double transpositions).
Let $H$ be any subgroup of order $2$ in $K$ (i.e. $H$ consists of any double transposition together with the identity).
Since $K$ is abelian, $H$ is normal in $K$. But $G$ acts transitively on the non-identity elements of $K$ by conjugation, so no proper non-trivial subgroup of $K$ can be normal in $G$ (hence $H$ is not normal in $G$).